# How to pass parameter that can be of type int/double/string/int[] from C# to native C?

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, native, managed

Can it be done something like this:

Native DLL:

```
void SetFieldValue(const char *Field, void *pValue, int Count)
{
    char *StrValue;
    int *IntArrayValue;
    if (!strcmp(Field, "StrField"))
    {
        StrValue = malloc((Count + 1) * sizeof(char)); 
        strcpy(StrValue, (char *)pValue);
        DoSomethingWithStringValue(StrValue);
        free(StrValue);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(Field, "IntArrayField"))
    {
        IntArrayValue = malloc(Count * sizeof(int)); 
        memcpy(IntArrayValue, pValue, Count);
        DoSomethingWithIntArrayValue(IntArrayValue);
        free(StrValue);
    }
    //... and so on
}
```

Managed:

```
[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention)]
private static extern void SetFieldValue(string fieldName, IntPtr value, int count);


public void SetIntArray()
{
    int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
    SetFieldValue("IntArrayField", intArray, 3);
}


public void SetString()
{
    SetFieldValue("StrField", "SomeValue", 9);
}

//... and so on
```

Comment: What is your problem? Your code looks ok to me.

Comment: My problem is that PInvoke is notorious to cause hard to find bugs. I'm trying to get opinions how these kind of things are best/most safely done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use method overloading. On the C# side you would declare multiple versions of the imported function. For the two examples in the question that would look like this:

```
[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention)]
private static extern void SetFieldValue(string fieldName, int[] value, int count);

[DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = DllCallingConvention)]
private static extern void SetFieldValue(string fieldName, string value, int count);
```

These two p/invoke functions are linked to the same single unmanaged function. For the first overload, the `value` argument is marshalled as a pointer to the first element of the array. For the second overload the `value` argument is marshalled as a pointer to a null-terminated character array. In both cases that is what you need.

Comment: thanks! this I've never heard about. so when doing like this, the native code is as in my question? this really seems like a neat way to do this.

Comment: Best to include an overload that uses a value type, too easy to forget to use `ref`.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, but I did not understand: "Best to include an overload that uses a value type, too easy to forget to use ref". I understood your overloading on managed side, but I was asking if my native C-code. C-does not have overloading.